# ng-if inside ng-repeat in a table AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

hey everyone am trying to use ng-if inside ng-repeat my condition is `if {{dev[2]}} == ""`  i wanna display in the `<td>Non Valide</td>` else i just wanna display the data inside the dev i've been looking about a lot of exemples but nothing look the same cause am trying to use if else does it even possible to make it this way here's my code :

```
<table  class="table table-bordered"   >
        <thead><tr class="infoti" >
        <th>Id Dev</th>
        <th>Nom Dev </th>
        <th>Nom Ecu</th>
        <th>Etat</th>
        <th>Action</th>
        <tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>     
<tr dir-paginate=" dev in devs | itemsPerPage:7 ">
            <td >{{dev[0]}}</td>
            <td>{{dev[1]}}</td>
            <td>{{dev[2]}}</td>
            <td ng-if({{dev[2]}} != "") >non validé</td>

<td><button class="btn btn-gray" ng-click="displaydata(dev[0])"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" >Validé</button></td>
</tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
```

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `ng-bind` to bind conditional data on view.

```
<td ng-bind="dev[2] != ''? 'Non Validé': 'Validé'"></td>
```

Comment: `<td ng-if="dev[2] == '' ">Non Validé</td>
<td ng-if="dev[2] != '' "> Validé</td>` i made this way and it worked but is it the proper way or should i use ng-bind